# What does "computably enumerated in increasing order" mean?

Tags: definition, computability

Some people used the terms "*computably enumerated in increasing order*". But I can't find formal definition about it.

*Computably enumerable set* means that range of some total computable function. So I think that the set $S$ is computably enumerated in increasing order iff there exists total computable function $f:A \rightarrow S$ such that for $a,b\in S$, $a<b$ implies $f(a)\leq f(b)$. But I have two questions if my definition is right.

1. Can we always think $A$ is subset of $N$?
2. How to define the order in arbitrary computably enumerable set $S$?

Comment: Your definition is correct. Do you have an example of an author using the terminology for a set $S$ that is not a set of natural numbers?

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb N$ could conceivably be computably enumerable, but not computably enumerated in increasing order.

Comment: @GEdgar In fact, this will be the case for any computably enumerable noncomputable set: from a computable in-order enumeration we can tell whether a number $x$ is in or out of the set in question (just wait until either $x$ enters the set, or something larger than $x$ enters the set without $x$ having previously entered the set).

Comment: @Lee.HW: there are basically two conventions for computable functions. In one of them, which is predominant in mathematics, computable functions always take and return natural numbers, and any other objects (e.g. binary strings) are only represented by coding. In the other convention, computable functions take and return strings on a finite alphabet, and again any other objects (e.g. natural numbers) are represented with coding.  In the setting where they would say "enumerated in increasing order", all the inputs and outputs will be natural numbers.